# Google Guava Maps vs Java Util Map

Tags: java, guava

While checking out open source code, I many times encounter statements like

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
```

where `Maps` is of package `com.google.common.collect.Maps` (Google Guava)

Why can't we simply use the standard:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

instead?

Comment: See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point here: before Java introduced the diamond operator, you had to *repeat* the generic type parameter when going for

```
Map<Whatever> myMap = new HashMap<Whatever>()
```

The guava call allowed you to avoid repeating `Whatever`. In other words: this is nothing but a convenience method that isn't useful (and thus deprecated) since Java has the diamond operator. And its [JavaDoc clearly explains](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap--) that.

> newHashMap
>
> public static  HashMap newHashMap()
>
> …
>
> Note for Java 7 and later: this method is now unnecessary and should be treated as deprecated. Instead, use the HashMap constructor directly, taking advantage of the new "diamond" syntax.

Comment: "In other words: this is nothing but a convenience method that isn't useful". You are right and in fact, it is the case for many concepts introduced by Java often latter. With Java 8 that brings many improvements pulled from Guava (but not only), in fact many Guava classes and methods are not needed any longer as now standard in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered by the [JavaDoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet--):

> **Note for Java 7 and later:** this method is now unnecessary and should be treated as deprecated. Instead, use the `HashSet` constructor directly, taking advantage of the new "diamond" syntax.